# TCP Sack panic proof of concept?

Tags: vulnerability, tcp

For the vulnerability called TCP SACK panic([1], [2], [3], and many more): is there a proof of concept code out there that can be used to test vulnerability status and effectiveness of remedies?

[1] https://github.com/Netflix/security-bulletins/blob/master/advisories/third-party/2019-001.md

[2] https://access.redhat.com/security/vulnerabilities/tcpsack

[3] https://isc.sans.edu/diary/What+You+Need+To+Know+About+TCP+%22SACK+Panic%22/25046

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a proof of concept on github:

https://github.com/sasqwatch/cve-2019-11477-poc

Comment: That Github repo has been deleted; does anyone have a copy of it?

Comment: Seems renamed/moved to https://github.com/sasqwatch/cve-2019-11477-poc